# Use docker-compose correctly so that two containers can files in the same volume

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've got a laravel application (based on laradock) that is amended to productionize it.

[github](https://github.com/spacelinx/laradock/blob/feature/os/sql-server/docker-compose.yml)

I'm trying to build a solution where:

1. files are copied from host to php app to a volume.  As you can see in the docker file here, the files are copied into the image: [image file copy](https://github.com/spacelinx/laradock/blob/feature/os%2Fsql-server/php-fpm/Dockerfile#:%7E:text=COPY%20./app/%20/var/www/) and composer update is running as expected.
   [composer update](https://github.com/spacelinx/laradock/blob/feature/os%2Fsql-server/php-fpm/Dockerfile#:%7E:text=no-dev%20--optimize%20%5C-,%26%26%20composer%20update,-%23%20Configure%20locale.)
2. php app is built in docker (the composer update command needs to run on the volume)
3. when docker-compose up is called, multiple containers start and nginx and php-fpm share the same content.  The Nginx container can therefore server php application.

When i run the code in the repo above, i am seeing a 404 in the browser.  The reason is (i think) because in the docker-compose file, on line 97, the statement:

```
    - app-data:/var/www/
```

(mounting the volume), has erased the files that have been added as it mounts.  (These files are being correctly added to the image as part of the docker build php-fpm.).

So, the question is, how can i mount a volume at run time, and not erase the files that have been added as part of image build?  The volume needs to be added to that path so that both containers can see the files (AFAIK).

Comment: The usual answer is to put the data in a different directory from the application code, and mount a volume only over the data directory.  You shouldn't usually mount a volume or host directory over the application code; use the code that's built into the Docker image.

Comment: (Better still would be to not share files between containers at all, and have one container send the other the data via an HTTP interface or something similar.  This works better in distributed environments like Kubernetes, but is potentially a major change in your application.)

Comment: thanks David.  I'm interested in the 2nd approach. Any examples that you can link me to with how i could implement this?  Perhaps please add an answer and i'll accept. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Docker volume will persist it data except the first time created it will use your container data to init the volume. I guess that you have wrongly created the volume before. So you just need to manually delete the `app-data` volume and re-deploy your docker-compose file.

- Stop your docker compose
- `docker volume rm <project_name_or_stack_name>_app-data`
- Start yout docker compose again

Besides, you will need to make sure that your php-fpm which contains your source code data will be started first before any other services sharing app-data volume.